# Existence of square roots and logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an open connected set in the complex plane on which the identity function has an analytic square root but not an analytic logarithm?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to use your hint. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: If I have an analytic logarithm I can define an analytic square root from it. I am asking for the converse. An analytic square root does not give me an analytic logarithm in any simple way.

Comment: The question has been answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2624819/42969, is that correct?

Comment: @MartinR You are right. David Ullrich's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a connected open set on which an analytic square root can be defined.  Then it follows easily that $U$ cannot contain the origin, and every closed curve in $U$ must have even [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) around the origin.  But any closed curve in the plane with nonzero winding number around the origin contains in its image a simple closed curve with winding number one around the origin, so $U$ cannot have any closed curves with nonzero winding number around the origin, and hence an analytic logarithm exists on $U$.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134665/does-a-branch-of-a-square-root-determine-a-branch-of-a-logarithm?rq=1).

Comment: *"... any closed curve in the plane with nonzero winding number around the origin contains in its image a simple closed curve with winding number one around the origin ..."* – I *think* that is intuitively clear to me, but could you give a hint how to prove that rigorously?

Comment: I just noticed that the solution to my question is easy: it is a consequence of the proof of Riemann Mapping Theorem. For example we can take w_0=0 in the proof of that theorem in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. Thus the region is necessarily simply connected.

Comment: I withdraw my last comment. Riemann Mapping Theorem requires existence of square roots for all holomorphic functions that don't have zeros.  I Don't understand Jim Belk's argument. Apart from the question raised by Martin, I also don't understand the last step in Jim's Argument.

Comment: I agree that my argument skips over some important details.  Unfortunately, I don't have time to work on filling these in, so I've placed a bounty on the question in the hopes of attracting someone else to give a more complete answer.